# MonoDevelop security error when trying to run a website on Windows

Tags: c#-4.0, mono, monodevelop, orchardcms

Perhaps this is just a bug in MonoDevelop but I am trying to build an Orchard website using MonoDevelop on Windows7.   I am using the latest MonoDevelp v 2.6b1 and when I try to run Orchard v 1.0 which can be downloaded directly from Codeplex I get the following error.  Seems like a partial trust error but I don't get this error when using Visual Studio 2010.  (I am trying to see how easily I can create an Orchard Website using only Open Source/Free tools).

Adding applications '/:.'...

Registering application:

```
Host:          any

Port:          any

Virtual path:  /

Physical path: C:\dev\Orchard.Source.1.0.20\src\Orchard.Web\
```

Handling exception type SecurityException

Message is That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.

IsTerminating is set to True

```
System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(RuntimeAssembly asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstan
Unhandled Exception: System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(RuntimeAssembly asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.RealMain(String[] args, Boolean root, IApplicationHost ext_apphost, Boolean quiet)
   at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.Main(String[] args)
   at Application.Xsp.Main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you are running on Mono, for one, as Mono does not implement this security system.  Make sure you tell MD that you want to run on Mono if that's what you intend.

As for actually running it on Mono, you might want to look at this thread: http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/247340.

Comment: My Goal is not to run Orchard on Mono but to be able to develop on Orchard using MonoDevelop.